# Using while loop to output input name backwards

Tags: python

I am on a step of a question that I cannot answer. The first part is:

```
full_name = input('Enter your full name ')
```

The second part is to use a `while` loop to print the name out backwards like from `'John Finger'` to `'regniF nhoJ'`.

It has to be done using a `while` loop, which is kind of weird to me since nothing I have read demonstrates anything like that with a `while` loop.

Comment: why does it *have to* be done in a while loop?

Comment: That is what the question is asking, and I am completely clueless on this part...

Comment: @khajvah This is some sort of task to study python, if I were to guess

Comment: This is a very simple problem. But it's recommended that you must try it yourself and comeback with your tried solution. We can then get back with corrections to be made.

Comment: Yes, you have to make some sort of effort. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    reverse_name =""
    i = len(full_name)
    while i > 0:
        reverse_name += full_name[i-1]
        i -=1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the usual way to do this:

```
print(full_name[::-1])
```

But this is probably what is meant:

```
full_name = input('Enter your full name ')

pos = len(full_name) - 1
while pos >= 0:
    print(full_name[pos], end="")
    pos -= 1

print()
```

There are several different way to do this, and it is a standard programming exercise which would work (in principle) in many languages.  It is not *Pythonic* though.  The problem is that a new string object is created for each character, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
name = 'John Finger'

index = len(name) - 1
while index >= 0:
    sys.stdout.write(name[index])
    index -= 1
```

Comment: Your `print` statement indicates python 2.  Since the question is using `input()` rather than `raw_input()` then I think we can assume python 3.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Length**: Get Length of string by `len` in-build function.
2. Decrement count by `1` because string index start from the `0`
3. Apply `while` loop with condition `count greater then -1`.
4. **String Concatenation**: Add two string variables.
5. Print result.

**Demo**:

```
>>> full_name = "John Finger"
>>> result = ""
>>> count = len(full_name)
>>> print "lenght:", count
lenght: 11
>>> count -= 1
>>> while count>-1:
...   result +=full_name[count]
...   count -= 1
... 
>>> result
'regniF nhoJ'
```